# AWS S3 Multipart upload working when not specifying source file

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've built an ajax uploader that uploads the files directly to S3, it works flawlessly the thing I'm confused on is how it's actually working. I've taken a different approach to how it's shown in the documentation, by instead of specifying the sourceFile the file name is being specified in the metadata. No file location is being sent.

I'm using `AWS SDK 2.4.3`

```
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key' => AWS_KEY,
    'secret' => AWS_SECRET
));

$extension = pathinfo($this->request->query['fileInfo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$model = $client->createMultipartUpload(array(
    'Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    'Key' => uniqid() . '.' . $extension, // Files don't share same name
    'ContentType' => $this->request->query['fileInfo']['type'], // image/png
    'Metadata' => $this->request->query['fileInfo']
));
```

$this->request->query['fileInfo']

```
array(
    'name' => "image.png", 
    'type' => "image/png", 
    'size' => 196292, 
    'lastModifiedDate' => Wed Aug 20 2014 15:02:29 GMT+1200 (NZST)
);
```

SignUploadPart

```
$command = $client->getCommand('UploadPart',
    array(
    'Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    'Key' => $this->request->query['sendBackData']['key'], // 53fd39a185f43.png
    'UploadId' => $this->request->query['sendBackData']['uploadId'], // hSJuBm3dWCMM1b....
    'PartNumber' => $this->request->query['partNumber'],
    'ContentLength' => $this->request->query['contentLength']
));
$request = $command->prepare();
$client->dispatch('command.before_send', array('command' => $command));
$request->removeHeader('User-Agent');
$request->setHeader('x-amz-date', gmdate(DateFormat::RFC2822));
$client->dispatch('request.before_send', array('request' => $request));
```

Theres no reference to a temp file path anywhere, I've tried digging through the SDK but can't seem to find anything that shows a way to find the file. Also since this is being sent via AJAX it doesn't create a temp file.

Removing the `Metadata` `ContentType` and assigning a random `Key` in the `CreateMultipartUpload` still uploads the file, just ends up with the name specified in Key...  Had two other developers look at it and both can't figure out how it's working.

Comment: Is this all of your code? As written, it wouldn't even complete the multipart upload, as an additional operation is required to do that.

Comment: No this is only the top half where the files are being specified. Will edit to add how the UploadPart is being sent. Don't think the `completeMultipartUpload` is needed to show that the file path is not specified anywhere

Comment: From what you've posted so far, this shouldn't work. What evidence do you have that it is working?

Comment: That I have public urls to over hundreds of media, have other services that also copy the media from the public urls and encodes the media.

Comment: [Actually have all the code up on github if you want to test it](https://github.com/nbankzy/s3-multipart-upload-browser/tree/multi-upload)