# Multipart Upload from Browser to S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am currently developing a program using HTML5, javascript, and PHP to allow a user to upload a file (or files) to a S3 bucket. I have been able to use POST to accomplish this goal, but I ran into issues regarding large files. To get pass the large file issue, I sliced the file into individual blobs to are were the appended to formdata and POSTed to my PHP script. It seemed to work, until it hit a certain road block. Anyways, after searching and searching for similar solutions to my problem, I came across [this](https://github.com/ienzam/s3-multipart-upload-browser). They example seemed to solve my issue about uploading large files to S3, until I ran the script myself. When running it, I would get:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'You must specify a non-null value for the Body or SourceFile parameters.' in C:\vhosts******.com\db*****\s3-multipart-upload-browser-master\aws\Aws\Common\Client\UploadBodyListener.php:91

As you can see, I am getting this fatal error because I lack a body. However, the programmer's documentation and posts [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517754/aws-s3-multipart-upload-working-when-not-specifying-source-file) swears that he was able to accomplish this without specifing a body element for the "uploadPart" method call. I want to know is if anyone else has had a similar experience with this and has a solution for my dilemma.

**EDIT:** Here is the code chunk that I was referring to in "server.php"

```
case 'signuploadpart': {
        $command = $client->getCommand('UploadPart',
            array(
            'Bucket'        => TMP_IMG,
            'Key'           => $_REQUEST['sendBackData']['key'],
            'UploadId'      => $_REQUEST['sendBackData']['uploadId'],
            'PartNumber'    => $_REQUEST['partNumber'],
            'ContentLength' => $_REQUEST['contentLength']
        ));

        $request = $command->prepare(); //This is the call that is giving me issues

        // This dispatch commands wasted a lot of my times :'(
        $client->dispatch('command.before_send', array('command' => $command));
        $request->removeHeader('User-Agent');
        $request->setHeader('x-amz-date', gmdate(DateFormat::RFC2822));
        // This dispatch commands wasted a lot of my times :'(
        $client->dispatch('request.before_send', array('request' => $request));

        sendJson(array(
            'url' => $request->getUrl(),
            'authHeader' => (string) $request->getHeader('Authorization'),
            'dateHeader' => (string) $request->getHeader('x-amz-date'),
        ));
        break;
    }
```

Comment: "However, the programmer's documentation and posts here on stackoverflow swears that he was able to accomplish this without specifing a body element for the "uploadPart" method call." Both the OP there and the commenter indicate that they don't think it should have worked. Why would you rely on a clearly not-documented probable bug for functionality?

Comment: I wasn't planning to use the probable bug for functionality. The example that I saw was similar to what I was trying to accomplish with my own program (i.e. initiate a multipart upload then send blods to be added). I just found it strange that the programmers for both the post and the github repository are both claiming to do exactly the same thing. Anyways, I was wondering if there was a way similar to this using POST, FormData, and XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like he didn't understand his own code... The server seems to be signing the URLs, and then the browser is actually doing the upload with the signed URLs returned by the server.  That's what it looks like.

Comment: That does make sense as the raw_upload.html file that I am referencing is waiting for an url. The problem on my end is that I am not getting that url and it is coming in as undefined. In his server.php script, the program gets hung up on "$request = $command->prepare();" in the "signuploadpart" case state. I wonder if it is due to the order of which the next calls are made.